Issue Connecting to Telegram Wallet using tonconnect/ui-react Library in React Mini-App
I’m developing a React mini-app and using the tonconnect/ui-react library to add a “Connect to Wallet” feature. The connection works perfectly with most wallets like Tonkeeper and others. However, when I try to connect to the in-app Telegram wallet, it shows a successful connection message but the connection doesn’t actually go through.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import { useTonConnectUI } from '@tonconnect/ui-react';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const MAX_RETRIES = 3;
const RETRY_DELAY = 1000; // 1 second

export function useTonWallet() {
  const [tonConnectUI] = useTonConnectUI();
  const [wallet, setWallet] = useState(null);
  const [isConnecting, setIsConnecting] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = tonConnectUI.onStatusChange(walletInfo => {
      setWallet(walletInfo);
      setIsConnecting(false);
    });

    // Try to restore the connection
    tonConnectUI.setConnectRequestParameters({
      state: 'ready',
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [tonConnectUI]);

  const connect = useCallback(async (retryCount = 0) => {
    setIsConnecting(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      console.log('Attempting to connect wallet...');
      await tonConnectUI.connectWallet();
      console.log('Wallet connected successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to connect wallet:', error);

      if (error.message === 'Failed to fetch' && retryCount < MAX_RETRIES) {
        console.log(`Retrying connection (attempt ${retryCount + 1} of ${MAX_RETRIES})...`);
        setTimeout(() => connect(retryCount + 1), RETRY_DELAY);
        return;
      }

      if (error.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
        setError('Network error. Please check your internet connection and try again.');
      } else {
        setError('Failed to connect wallet. Please try again.');
      }
      setIsConnecting(false);
    }
  }, [tonConnectUI]);

  const disconnect = useCallback(() => {
    tonConnectUI.disconnect();
  }, [tonConnectUI]);

  return {
    wallet,
    connect,
    disconnect,
    tonConnectUI,
    isConnecting,
    error,
  };
}
  


Steps I’ve taken so far:
1.  Testing Other Wallets: The connection works perfectly with other wallets like Tonkeeper.
2.  Testing Across Multiple Mini-Apps: I tried the same connection with other Telegram mini-apps using the same library, and the issue persists.
3.  Logging and Debugging: I’ve added logging to trace the connection flow. The logs show that the connection is “successful,” but the actual connection does not seem to be established.
4.  Retry Logic: I’ve implemented a retry mechanism for network errors, but the issue doesn’t appear to be related to connectivity.

Environment:
•   React/nextjs
•   @tonconnect/ui-react library
•   Telegram Mini-App Environment

Questions:
•   Is there something specific about the Telegram mini-app environment that could be causing this issue?
•   Are there known issues with the Telegram wallet’s integration with tonconnect/ui-react?
•   Is there a specific configuration required for Telegram wallets that differs from other TON wallets?
•   Could this be related to how Telegram handles in-app connections or CORS policies?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
